# kubernetes commands working on Terminal but no iTerm2

Tags: macos, kubernetes, kubectl, iterm2

I have installed kubectl and kubectx through Terminal in my Mac. Commands work well only in Terminal. With iTerm2, I get connection issues.

Terminal:

```
  kubectl get pods
  NAME                                             READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
  actionprocessor-568c869cc6-jtjwg                 1/1       Running     0          16h
  hbridge-5b4964fc68-bmcnw                         1/1       Running     0          17h
  k2m-75cb44b7dc-svtpr                             1/1       Running     0          16h
  m2k-7c8bb5f9-vsrld                               1/1       Running     0          16h
```

iTerm:

```
  kubectl get pods
  Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 35.*.*.123:443: connect: host is down
  (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x106d13f98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 64] Host is down'))
```

I can basically do everything from Terminal. But from iTerm I cannot even connect to my hosted platforms using `gcloud` or `az cli`. Everything returns the same connectivity error.

Terminal ENV variables:

```
  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=421.1
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
  XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.lk29tXgG6a/Listeners
  TERM=xterm-256color
  SHELL=/usr/local/bin/zsh
  HOME=/Users/miguelcallejasp
  LOGNAME=miguelcallejasp
  USER=miguelcallejasp
  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
  SHLVL=1
  PWD=/Users/miguelcallejasp
  OLDPWD=/Users/miguelcallejasp
  ZSH=/Users/miguelcallejasp/.oh-my-zsh
  PAGER=less
  LESS=-R
  LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

iTerm2:

```
  Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9xV8EAQUEb/Render
  COLORFGBG=15;0
  ITERM_PROFILE=TermOld
  XPC_FLAGS=0x0
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  PWD=/Users/miguelcallejasp
  SHELL=/usr/local/bin/zsh
  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.2.7
  TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
  COLORTERM=truecolor
  TERM=xterm-256color
  HOME=/Users/miguelcallejasp
  USER=miguelcallejasp
  XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
  LOGNAME=miguelcallejasp
  __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x0:0:0
  SHLVL=1
  OLDPWD=/Users/miguelcallejasp/Library
  ZSH=/Users/miguelcallejasp/.oh-my-zsh
  PAGER=less
  LESS=-R
  LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
  _=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Comment: I would look for any software installed that can affect iTerm2 and block connection.

Comment: you need to provide more info beside env vars, can you please share `traceroute`,`ip addr show`,`ip route show`, `ping`?